# How can I solve attribute error for Pandas : "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Float64Dtype"?

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I am trying to read a .sav file. For this, I have installed pyreadstat using

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyreadstat
```

but when I run the following line of code (before even getting to reading the file):

```
import pyreadstat
```

I get this error: "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Float64Dtype' ".

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Complete error is as follows

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import pandas
----> 2 import pyreadstat

File ~\anaconda3\envs\dhdsblend2021\lib\site-packages\pyreadstat\__init__.py:17, in <module>
      1 # #############################################################################
      2 # Copyright 2018 Hoffmann-La Roche
      3 #
   (...)
     14 # limitations under the License.
     15 # #############################################################################
---> 17 from .pyreadstat import read_sas7bdat, read_xport, read_dta, read_sav, read_por, read_sas7bcat
     18 from .pyreadstat import write_sav, write_dta, write_xport, write_por
     19 from .pyreadstat import set_value_labels, set_catalog_to_sas

File pyreadstat\pyreadstat.pyx:1, in init pyreadstat.pyreadstat()

File pyreadstat\_readstat_writer.pyx:42, in init pyreadstat._readstat_writer()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\dhdsblend2021\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:258, in __getattr__(name)
    254     from pandas.core.arrays.sparse import SparseArray as _SparseArray
    256     return _SparseArray
--> 258 raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
```

Comment: What version of pandas is installed in your environment? I cannot reproduce the error in 1.4.2

Comment: I have '1.1.5'. Is this the problem?

Comment: Most likely, try updating pandas to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Pyreadstat requires Pandas 1.2.0 at the very minimum. Please try updating pandas to a newer version.